# Able to SSH into remote server, but unable to git push production

Tags: git, ssh, putty, cmder

I am following [this guide](https://devmarketer.io/learn/deploy-laravel-5-app-lemp-stack-ubuntu-nginx/) Step 12 on how to setup pushing to production on remote server.

I am getting access denied errors when I try to git push production master.

```
user@example.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

However, I am able to login via ssh root@example.com.

I am using Putty as well as Laragon on windows.

Comment: Can you share with us the **actual** error message?

Comment: Updated original post

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted. Did I ask something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem was done by removing the current production remote and re-adding it specifically using root user.